# C++ Passing a vector<vector<STRUCT> > for modifying

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

let's say I have a

```
vector<vector<foobar> > vector2D(3);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   vector2D[i].resize(3);
```

So, a 3x3 vector containing 9 elements of type foobar in total.

I know want to pass "vector2D" to a function to modify some values in "vector2D".
For example, if foobar contains

```
struct foobar{
       int *someArray;
       bool someBool;
}
```

I want to pass "vector2D" to a function that modifies vector2D like this:

```
vector2D[0][0].someArray = new int[100];
vector2D[0][0].someArray[49] = 1;
```

The function shouldn't return anything (call by reference).

Is this even possible?

Comment: FYI: You can initialize your vector without a loop: `vector<vector<foobar> > vector2D(3,vector<foobar>(3));`

Comment: thanks, in my normal usecase the vector is initialized during runtime so i need the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  You just need to pass it in as a non-const reference.  Something like:

```
void ModifyVector( vector< vector< foobar > > & v )
{
    v[0][0].someArray = new int[100];
    v[0][0].someArray[49] = 1;
}

vector<vector<foobar> > vector2D(3);
ModifyVector( vector2D );
```

One further note: you probably should implement the copy constructor for your `foobar` struct if you're using it within a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just pass your vector2D by reference:

```
void foo(vector<vector<foobar> >& v)
{
    v[0].resize(3);
    v[0][0].someArray = new int[100];
    v[0][0].someArray[49] = 1
}
```

and call it as:

```
vector<vector<foobar> > vector2D(3);
foo(vector2D);
```